# Functions agree at all but finitely many points implies integrability.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am given the following problem

Show that if $g$ satisfies $g(x) = f(x)$ for all but a finite number of points in $[a,b]$ and $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable , then $g$ is integrable as well.

Take a partition $P^\prime$ such that $P^\prime$ only contains a finite number of points where $g(x)=f(x)$ and where $P^\prime$ doesn't contain any points where $g(x)\not=f(x)$. Notice that $g(x)=f(x)$ for every point in this partition, hence
$$
U(g,P^\prime)=U(f,P^\prime)
$$
and
$$
L(g,P^\prime)=L(f,P^\prime).
$$
Since $f$ is integrable (the fact that $f$ is integrable means it is bounded and hence $g$ is bounded in this partition) this means
$$
U(f,P^\prime)-L(f,P^\prime)<\epsilon.
$$
However $U(g,P^\prime)=U(f,P^\prime)$ and $L(g,P^\prime)=L(f,P^\prime)$ so
$$
U(g,P^\prime)-L(g,P^\prime)<\epsilon.
$$
Hence $g$ is integrable by theorem 7.2.8.

Note here theorem 7.2.8 is a theorem that states

a bounded function f is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if there is some partition $P_\epsilon$ of $[a,b]$ such that

$$
U(f,P_\epsilon)-L(f,P_\epsilon)<\epsilon
$$
I am wondering if my solution is valid. I think it is but maybe I am misunderstanding the statement of the theorem. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I updated my post. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: It's clearer now after your edits. However, how do you know that your partition $P'$ satisifes $U(f,P^\prime)-L(f,P^\prime)<\epsilon$? This isn't true of all partitions. Rather, integrability of $f$ ensures that there *exists* a partition $P$ with this property. But this $P$ may contain points for which $f(x) \neq g(x)$. So you'll have to deal with that somehow.

Comment: To make life easier, consider f and g differs by only one point. How do you show g is integrable then?

Comment: Exercise 3-2 from Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak:

Let A⊂Rn, f:A→R an integrable (in the sense of Darboux) function. Let g=f except at finitely many points. Prove that g is also integrable and ∫Af=∫Ag.

Answer (score 0):

To show g is integrable, you have to take an arbitrary partition P of [a b] such that

U(g,P) - L(g,P) <ϵ. for every partition P of [ a b].

NOT just the lucky partition common to f and g for which they agree.

**Hint:    Find a partition P such that it includes points where f and g disagree.**

**Question:  Can you go from here?**

Comment: In the textbook I am using, Understanding Analysis by Abbot, the theorem states that there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$

Comment: Be specific on your proof.
How do you construct the partition that abbot has in his mind?